# Difference between $\mathbb{C}P^2$ and $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Sorry for the trouble, I got confused between $\mathbb{C}P^2$ and $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$, do they have the same Euler characteristic? the same signature? does $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ admit a Kahler-Einstein metric? is $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ Fano? does $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ admit Fubini-Study metric？ Thank you.

Comment: You have made quite a lot of questions in a single post. Please avoid this.

Comment: What's $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$?

Comment: @John Ma It is $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with opposite orientation.

Comment: So do you consider the usual Kahler form on $\mathbb {C}P^2$ a Kahler form on $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$?

Comment: For a beotian like me who only wants to enlarge his culture, what is $\mathbb{C}P^2$ ? I know for example what is a Fano plane, but I am puzzled by such a compact expression as "is $\mathbb{C}P^2$ Fano"... It sounds me like SMS abbreviations...

Comment: @JeanMarie: $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is the complex projective plane. "Fano" is short for "Fano variety" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_variety), and as far as I know has nothing to do with the Fano plane.

Comment: Thank you very much @Qiaochu Yuan I should have guessed for $\mathbb{CP}^2$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your confusion is due to not keeping track of what categories everything is living in. $\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$, as a smooth manifold, is still just $\mathbb{CP}^2$. So it has the same smooth-manifold invariants as $\mathbb{CP}^2$, such as Euler characteristic.

$\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$, as an *oriented* smooth manifold, is $\mathbb{CP}^2$ with the opposite orientation. The signature of an oriented manifold flips when you flip its orientation, so the signature of $\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ is the negative of the signature of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ ($-1$ instead of $1$).

As far as I know, $\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ does not admit a complex structure consistent with its orientation (recall that a complex structure determines an orientation), so it is not a complex manifold in a way interestingly different from the way that $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is a complex manifold. So it's unclear how to interpret your other questions.

Said another way, when we talk about $\mathbb{CP}^2$ we are really talking about an object living in many categories, related by a sequence of forgetful functors

$$\text{ComplexMan} \to \text{OrientedSmoothMan} \to \text{SmoothMan} \to \text{TopMan}$$

none of which reflect isomorphisms, and when we talk about $\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ we are talking about an object living in all of these categories except $\text{ComplexMan}$, which is only different from $\mathbb{CP}^2$ in $\text{OrientedSmoothMan}$. It's important to keep track of these things.

Comment: You are correct that $\overline{\Bbb{CP^2}}$ does not admit a complex structure. This follows as a corollary of Noether's formula, which gives $c_1^2(S) = 3\sigma(S) + 2\chi(S)$ for any complex surface. For $S = \overline{\Bbb{CP}^2}$, the right hand side is $3$, which is bad for two reasons: 1) the LHS is nonpositive, because the intersection form on $S$ is negative definite; 2) $H_2$ is 1-dimensional and 3 is not a square.